# How to check if ListItem DisplayName is initialized in CSOM (SP2013)?

Tags: 2013, csom

I currently have code that looks like this:

```
public static string GetListItemDisplayName(ClientContext clientContext, ListItem listItem)
    {
        string displayName;
        try
        {
            displayName = listItem.DisplayName;
        }
        catch
        {
            clientContext.Load(listItem, args => args.DisplayName);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            displayName = listItem.DisplayName;
        }
        return listItem.DisplayName;
    }
```

I have the feeling that using a trycatch this is not the most elegant solution to check if the ListItem DisplayName has been initiated. Is there any other way to do it? 
I have tried to use `clientContext.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("DisplayName")` but that doesn't seem to work the way I thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the property has been initialized by using the following code:

```
if (listItem.IsObjectPropertyInstantiated("DisplayName"))
{
//your code here
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536724.aspx) is the MSDN page that describes the property in details.

Comment: I have tried your solution, but the boolean always results in false on my end